# Generate CSR PKCS#10 with mulitple keys keys

Tags: java, security, cryptography, bouncycastle, pki

I have just started working on PKI concept and anything wrong in my explanation below, kindly excuse me.

Requirement is to generate CSR (PKCS#10) request to Registration authority (RA), In which the CSR will be signed with two keys (Both sub and main keys). later RA validates request and uses his own certificate, signs it and sends request to CA.

Keys are generated using the bouncy castle API with ECDSA algorithm. Even the generated PKCS#10 CSR (from program below) and signed with sub keys now. As show in the code below.

But the below program is signed with only sub key and i need an idea how we can sign the entire PKCS#10 CSR again or with PKCS#7 with a Main key and send the entire package to RA for issuing a certificate from CA with some validation check in RA.

Bouncy caste maven version org.bouncycastle : 1.56

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.RDN;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.BCStyle;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentVerifierProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.jcajce.JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;

public class BouncyCastleTest {
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    private static final String PROVIDER = "BC";
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "ECDSA";
    private static final String SIGNING_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withECDSA";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BouncyCastleTest bcObject = new BouncyCastleTest();

        //1. Generate Key pair for Main and Sub keys
        KeyPair subKeyPair = bcObject.generateKeyPair("secp256r1");
        KeyPair mainKeyPair = bcObject.generateKeyPair("secp384r1");

        //2. Generate PKCS 10 request and sign with subKeyPair
        PKCS10CertificationRequest csrRequest = generatePKCS10Request(subKeyPair);

        //3. TODO sign the entire pkcs#10 message with main key?

        //4. read the content of the PKCS #10 CSR request
        readCSR(csrRequest);
    }

    private static PKCS10CertificationRequest generatePKCS10Request(KeyPair keyPair) {
        System.out.println("--- GENERATE PKCS#10 Format CSR ---");
        PKCS10CertificationRequest certRequest = null;
        ContentSigner signGen;

        //TODO Check for how to sign the CSR with MAIN keys
        //TODO some more attributes/values adding to CSR (Ex: port, serial num, destination, typeId etc)
        try {
            //Generating signature with sub private key
            signGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(SIGNING_ALGORITHM).build(keyPair.getPrivate());

            X500Name issuerDetails = new org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name("CN=127.0.0.1, O=FOO, L=BAR, ST=BAZ, C=QUX");

            //sign the PKCS10 request add the sub public key to the message
            PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrP10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(issuerDetails, keyPair.getPublic());

            certRequest = csrP10Builder.build(signGen);

            System.out.println("--- GENERATED PKCS#10 Format CSR ---");
        } catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return certRequest;
    }

    private KeyPair generateKeyPair(String specification) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
            ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec(specification);
            keyPairGen.initialize(spec);

            return keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void readCSR(PKCS10CertificationRequest csr) {

        System.out.println("--- READ PKCS#10 Format CSR ---");
        try {
            //Validate the signature of the CSR
            ContentVerifierProvider verifierProvider = new JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder().setProvider(PROVIDER).build(csr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo());

            if(csr.isSignatureValid(verifierProvider)) {
                System.out.println("\n-- SIGNATURE VERIFIED ---");

                X500Name x500Name = csr.getSubject();
                System.out.println("x500Name is: "  + x500Name + "\n");

                System.out.println("Common name: "  + getX500Field(BCStyle.CN, x500Name));
                System.out.println("Organization: " + getX500Field(BCStyle.O, x500Name));
                System.out.println("Country: "      + getX500Field(BCStyle.C, x500Name));
                System.out.println("State: "         + getX500Field(BCStyle.ST, x500Name));

                //TODO read attributes/values added to CSR (Ex: port, serial num, destination, typeId etc)
            } else {
                System.out.println("-- INVALID SIGNATURE ---");
            }
        } catch (OperatorCreationException | PKCSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static String getX500Field(ASN1ObjectIdentifier asn1ObjectIdentifier, X500Name x500Name) {
        RDN[] rdnArray = x500Name.getRDNs(asn1ObjectIdentifier);
        String retVal = null;
        for (RDN item : rdnArray) {
            retVal = item.getFirst().getValue().toString();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I have following task which needs to be implemented and needs an idea on how I can complete these tasks. In the program, you can be found those as TODO task.
1) Check for how to sign/generate the CSR which signed by MAIN key.
2) Needs to add some more attributes/values to PKCS#10 CSR (Ex: port, serial num, destination, typeId etc)

But the main part is to how we can generate CSR with signing multiple keys? and is there any alternate way to fix?

Comment: If you look at the PKCS10 document (section 4.2) it allows one and exactly one signature on a CSR. Even the more general and rarely used rfc4211 (and rfc5272) does only one PoP. You'll have to do something else, maybe wrap the CSR in PKCS7/CMS SignedData.

Comment: Clever the way you emphasized the multiplicity of the keys in your title.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, any sample code for to generate PKCS7/CMS signed data which includes PKCS10 csr data for my above program? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you're already using BC, have a look at [the javadoc for CMSSignedDataGenerator](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html) which includes simple example code (although you probably want encapsulate=true not false)